# Min Heap Custom Comparator in C++

Tags: c++, stl, heap

I have a Point Class and am creating a min-heap of Point objects.

```
class Point
{
   int x;
   int y;
public:
   Point(int _x, int _y)
   {
      x = _x;
      y = _y;
   }
   int getX() const { return x; }
   int getY() const { return y; }
};
 
// To compare two points
class myComparator
{
public:
    int operator() (const Point& p1, const Point& p2)
    {
        return p1.getX() > p2.getX();
    }
};

int main() {
priority_queue<Point,vector<Point>,myComparator> pq;
pq.push(Point(2,3));
pq.push(Point(3,4));
return 0;
}
```

If I want to create a min-heap based on smaller value of x in every Point object.
Why is it p1.getX() > p2.getX() and not p1.getX() < p2.getX() since I think p1 is the parent and p2 is the child and then parent should be less than child in min-heap. Please clear my confusion.

Comment: Parent and child? I don't see any inheritance here, what do you mean "parent and child"? Also, even if there were inheritance, I don't think an `>` or `<` operator would have anything to do with it.

Comment: Don't see how it helps to copy/paste, without adding anything, the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66193178/min-heap-custom-comparator-in-c) you asked yesterday which was closed for lack of details after you failed to follow up on the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> ```
> template<
>    class T,
>    class Container = std::vector<T>,
>    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
> ```
>
> ...
>
> A priority queue is a container adaptor that provides constant time lookup of the **largest** (by default) element, at the expense of logarithmic insertion and extraction.
>
> A user-provided Compare can be supplied to change the ordering, e.g. using std::greater would cause the smallest element to appear as the top().

By default std::priority_queue uses the [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) comparator to sort the priority queue in a way that elements with higher values are **prioritized**.

If you want smaller values to be handled first, you need to inverse that function by providing a comparator that return a lower rank the higher the value is.